# Problems with the chain rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose, $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, and $\gamma\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to compute $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(f(\gamma(t))\right)$.

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2f}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{df}{d\gamma}\cdot\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right) = \frac{d^2f}{d\gamma^2}\cdot\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{df}{d\gamma}\cdot\frac{d^2\gamma}{dt^2}\right)
\end{align}

But how to compute $\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)^2$?...

Please help.

Comment: What is $df/d\gamma$ and how do you square the vector $d\gamma/dt$?

Comment: Ok, it has no sense at all. Can you show me how to calculate it? I am thinking about some theoretical problem and i got stuck here. It is very annoying. $d\gamma/dt$ is just $\gamma'(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ then $$f(\gamma(t))=f(x(t),y(t)).$$ Thus

$$(f\circ \gamma)'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y'(t).$$

Proceed in the same way to get $(f\circ \gamma)''(t).$